# how to set a page in Struts2 to automatically redirect the wrong urls

Tags: jsp, struts2

I need to redirect the incorrect URL to my server to a specific page.
how can I make that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default action for that in your struts.xml. See http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-ActionDefault.

Or there is also `Unknown Handlers` in Struts2 http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/unknown-handlers.html if you need a more complex solution.

Comment: Any example of Unknown Handlers of how to use them inside implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=jsp/login.jsp">
```

it will automatically redirect to the specified in the url position.