# How to define a global page when requested page or method is not found?

Tags: java, exception, struts2, global, struts-config

I know how to fine a global error redirect page in our defined package when exception encountered that just by adding the following configuration in the parent package in `struts.xml`:

```
<global-results>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</global-results>

<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error" />
</global-exception-mappings>
```

But It seems to not able to catch those exceptions like requested resources, methods, pages are not found, I mean how to catch the struts2-level errors, and then I can do something to handle it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313279/struts-2-how-to-redirect-exceptions-of-type-exception-to-a-particular-page-bu

Comment: I can catch the my action's exceptions, but cannot catch struts2's own exception like requested pages is not found.

Comment: ohh! that you can configure in action's result tag. If result is input or error give page `error.jsp`

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/16293143/1700321 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12795634/1700321.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your unknown handler in the `struts.xml`. Unknown handlers are called by the framework, when an unknown action, result, or method are executed.

```
<bean type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandler" name="handler" class="com.package.SomeUnknownHandler"/>
```

The class should implement `UknownHandler` interface to handle the cases:

- when an action configuration is unknown
- when a result cannot be found for an action and result code
- when an action method cannot be found

Comment: Thanks for pointing me a mind. And now the question I get is how should I implement the UnknownHandler interface, what logic should I do? throw a exception, or return the related object for redirect the URL I handle it??

Comment: It's up to you, actions usually redirect to known action, results to known result, method to known method.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. UknownHandler is exactly provides us a interface to catch these unknown cases and do the appropriate handlings, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here some detaiks a how you can use the `UknownHandler` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27881698/3383543), enjoy.