# Struts2 - Going to an Invalid URL does not redirect to mapped 404 page or give the default no action message

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, http-status-code-404

I do not know what configuration changes I may have done to cause this, but for some reason, going to an invalid URL which maps to no struts2 action, only gives a blank page. It does not redirect to the Mapped 404 page, and it does not even display the "There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name []" like it used to. I am trying to get my 404 page working, but I have no clue what is going on here. In my web.xml I have:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/error/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Have any idea as to why blank pages are being served with invalid URL's and actions?
I appreciate the help

Comment: This question lacks the configuration.

Comment: @RomanC Actually the problem was pretty dumb... with the location to the 404.jsp was wrong. The solution was to have /WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.jsp but I excluded the WEB-INF directory because web.xml is stored in that so I figured that's where it would check.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand, could you post your JSP?

Answer (score 3):

Finally -  After deep searching about this issue, I'll find a great solution to how get this works as probably!

**1st:** you need to add the *com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandler* bean in your **struts.xml**:

```
<bean type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandler" name="handler" class="com.path.to.your.InvalidRequests"/>
```

**2nd:** setup an action to refer into the page not found behavior.

```
<action name="pageNotFound" class="com.path.to.your.PageNotFound" method="execute">
   <result name="success">/jsps/404.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**3rd:** in your custom handler you need to define your *com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.entities.ActionConfig* and check if the action is already exists in your action configuration lists

```
public class InvalidRequests implements UnknownHandler {
@Override
public ActionConfig handleUnknownAction(String namespace, String actionName) throws XWorkException {
    ConfigurationManager configurationManager = Dispatcher.getInstance().getConfigurationManager();
    RuntimeConfiguration runtimeConfiguration = configurationManager.getConfiguration().getRuntimeConfiguration();
    ActionConfig actionConfig = runtimeConfiguration.getActionConfig(namespace, actionName);
    if(actionConfig == null) { // invalid url request, and this need to be handled
        actionConfig = runtimeConfiguration.getActionConfig("", "pageNotFound");
    }
    return actionConfig;
}
// ... also you need to implements handleUnknownResult, handleUnknownActionMethod
}
```

Keep in mind you need to override the both of methods *handleUnknownResult* and *handleUnknownActionMethod* and the both of methods return **null**.

Comment: In second step what is the class com.path.to.your.PageNotFound for?

Comment: It is an action class that you need to create it for 404 requests. Something like this should work: public class NotFound extends ActionSupport {
    @Override
    public String execute() {
       return ERROR;
    }
}