# Struts 2 custom 404 error page never shows

Tags: jsp, struts2, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I'm using the Struts 2 framework for a webapp. While trying to create a custom 404 error page I discovered Struts 2 is doing more work for me then intended.

I only use a `struts.xml` and a `web.xml` file. In the `web.xml` file I added the following code:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/Error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Now, when I start my webapp it goes to the homepage as usual. When I try urls of this type (all urls that don't exist):

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/fhgfhfhfhgfhgfhfhfh
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/fhgfhfhfhgfhgfhfhfh.action
```

Struts will process the request, run the interceptors, and automatically redirect to the default page. I would have expected my 404 error page to be shown on these pages. I even removed this line in `struts.xml` but it still redirects!

```
<default-action-ref name="index" />
```

When I use the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/fhgfhfhfhgfhgfhfhfh.jsp
```

Struts just shows a blank screen and no request is being processed (no interceptors, no redirecting...). I find this weird too because I don't see what's invalid about that request (other than the JSP file that doesn't exist)

So I guess I need to modify my `struts.xml` so I can override some default redirecting behaviour (I don't want the 404 error to be covered up by going to the homepage), and my `web.xml` to also handle any arbitrary obscure requests (so any URL that is being typed in by the user will at actually be handled instead of just showing blank screens. What am I missing in my configuration?

PS: I'm not talking about Java exceptions/errors, but only the HTTP errors. The Java exceptions are handled properly like I want them to behave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reasons why it was not showing.

The problem with blank screen was as follows: the path to my 404 page was not correct. It should be the path starting from the webContent folder, and starting with a slash "/".

The problem with the default action was probably a server reboot or cache problem. I close my browser and my IDE, and restarted everything. Then the default-action-ref was REALLY gone.

I also discovered another interesting quirk: struts2 handles only action mappings, for example:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/webapp/whatever
http://www.mywebsite.com/webapp/whatever.action
```

but it will NOT handle server resources like this (notice the file extensions)

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/webapp/whatever.zip
http://www.mywebsite.com/webapp/whatever.jsp
http://www.mywebsite.com/webapp/whatever.html
```

You can remedy this by adding an additional filter mapping in the web.xml file:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/error/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: for noticing and documenting this interesting quirk of adding filter mapping for errors

Answer (score 3):

To solve this you can simply add default namespace and create a action with reference as *. It will get executed by default if no action matched. Add the code below to struts.xml. It should work fine.

```
<package name="serveAll" namespace="" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*">
            <result>/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

Comment: This is a nice trick that I will certainly make good use of in another context. Unfortunately, it does not work for resources on the server, for example "myWebApp/afile.zip". If I go to that url, I will get my browser's 404 page.

Comment: It should work with .zip also. I tested. Also not only for .zip, even if we type .asdasd it will respond with error page. See http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/struts2-tutorial-part-5-namespaces/ for info.

Answer (score 1):

Struts 2 can be also configured to handle unknown action or result, even without `default-action-ref` tag it provides a configuration to process such requests.

Generally you can use `unknown-handler-stack` tag by the struts2 xml configuration and reference handlers. You should check that what `com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandler` is provided. Also see this answer [How to define unknown handler bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18505084/573032).

If you are using a convention plugin it supplies by default `convention` unknown handler, which could probably handle your action or result.

Comment: This is very useful and I implemented this just in case. Unfortunately, it does not work for resources on the server, for example "myWebApp/afile.zip". If I go to that url, I will get my browser's 404 page.

Comment: Does this resource exist?